# Dangers of converting delegates to function pointers

Tags: .net, c++, garbage-collection

Suppose you have a managed class that converts a delegate member to a native function pointer and hands it to native code.  Assume that the class/delegate stays in scope and does not change for the lifetime of the native code (so that will not be obviously destroyed by the GC).  What other problems should one be aware of in this situation?  For example, is it possible for the GC to move the delegate or the actual method the delegate refers to and leave your native code with an access violation?

Comment: "Stays in scope" is not meaningful with the other assertions in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it's possible to pin the memory location of the delegate/function, but this obstructs a major advantage of the .NET GC: compacting.

Once a GC sweep is done, every object is relocated in memory to be contiguous. This makes both access and allocation faster that it would be if the heap were fragmented.  If you have to pin an object in place in the heap, the GC would have to work around it and if it were done multiple times, it could lead to some nontrivial heap fragmentation. (By the way, this is addressed with GCHandle in the article linked by Ron Warholic. I'm not sure if that is available outside managed C++.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not much of a .Net expert, but I think you should take a look here : [Marshal Callbacks and Delegates Using C++ Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367eeye0%28VS.80%29.aspx).

> Notice that is it possible, but not
>   necessary, to pin the delegate using
>   pin_ptr to prevent it from being
>   re-located or disposed of by the
>   garbage collector. Protection from
>   premature garbage collection is
>   needed, but pinning provides more
>   protection than is necessary, as it
>   prevents collection but also prevents
>   relocation.

Comment: The following example is similar to the previous example, but in this case the provided function pointer is stored by the unmanaged API, so it can be invoked at any time, requiring that garbage collection be suppressed for an arbitrary length of time. As a result, the following example uses a global instance of GCHandle to prevent the delegate from being relocated, independent of function scope. As discussed in the first example, using pin_ptr is unnecessary for these examples, but in this case wouldn't work anyway, as the scope of a pin_ptr is limited to a single function.

Answer (score 2):

The GC can move the delegate, but not the native code the delegate wraps.  So as long as the delegate is not collected the function pointer will remain valid.

Note that "being in scope" is not sufficient to keep an object from being collected.  It has to be used (possibly by a call to `GC.KeepAlive`).

Comment: Not sure I follow, the delegate wraps a managed method that is called by native code, but +1 for the "has to be used"

Answer (score 2):

A quick search reveals some [Microsoft guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367eeye0.aspx) on the issue.  The article is for managed C++ but the guidance should hold for any language on the CLR.

The idea is that you need to prevent the delegate itself from being relocated or disposed but (naturally) the underlying code cannot move.  Once the JIT compiles to native code that code is fixed and should not move.